# Android - Aligning a view (button) within another View in code?

Tags: android, mobile, button, layout, view

I have a custom view which will be jar'ed up and added into another project. In the view I want to give an option of a button.

Here is what I have in the CustomView class.

```
final CustomView currentView = (CustomView) findViewById(this.getId());

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (new   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));

params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
closeButton.setLayoutParams(params);

currentView.addView(closeButton);
```

This is all wrapped in a RelativeLayout Tag as well as the other objects of the application

Everything compiles however in the CustomView the Button is aligning left instead of right.Any Ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the problem is your CustomView. It probably doesn't take the entire width of the window, and is just wide enough to fill its children (which, in your case, is the close button). Make sure your CustomView has a `fill_parent` horizontal layout.

Since your CustomView extends WebView, which, in turn, extends AbsoluteLayout, you can't expect it to handle RelativeLayout's parameters.  Instead, it's best you put your customview and your close button inside a RelativeLayout and position them properly.

Comment: The CustomView has an image in it already and I am trying to align the close button the right corner of the image. :/

Comment: In that case, it's probably a bug in your custom view's layout code. Can you post it?

Comment: Post it in the original question... Also, I'm talking about how your custom view lays out its children, not about the XML.

Comment: Since I create the custom view within code I am not sure how the layout for the custom view is set?

Comment: What is your CustomView derived from?

Comment: Oh, well, a WebView extends AbsoluteLayout, no wonder it doesn't understand RelativeLayout parameters. See edit.

Comment: See the edit I've made to my answer -I've added more information.

Answer (score 0):

When adding your `closeButton` to your `currentView` you need to supply the LayoutParams as an argument as well in order for them to take effect.

Basically, switch

```
currentView.addView(closeButton);
```

with

```
currentView.addView(closeButton, params);
```

---

Since the width of your button is set to wrap_content, you could also try setting its layout_gravity to right.

```
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
```

Comment: does your custom view extend RelativeLayout?

Comment: In the layout xml it is under the same RelativeLayout tag that encompasses all the other objects in my application. So I believe so.

Comment: I'm referring to the class where you define your custom view.  It would need to subclass RelativeLayout in order for children added to it to respect RelativeLayout.LayoutParams properties.

Comment: Ahh my CustomView is in Absolute Layout. How do I go about changing this?

Comment: You should just add your Button to the parent view of your custom view, since you say it is a RelativeLayout.